# Would it be a violation if I use a custom currency symbol for iOS In-App purchase?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I have implemented IAP auto-renew feature on an application. It's working perfectly. Now my client is asking to use a custom symbol for the Japanese App Store only, which means users who are using App Store ID from japan, will see that custom currency symbol only. So my question is, If I implement this, would it be a cause of app store rejection?
Any Apple official link will be highly appreciable.